# Refresh token unique

Tags: oauth-2.0

Good evening:

I am implementing two-legged OAuth 2.0 and I wanted to know how to generate a "random" and unique refresh_token.

The user will send a refresh_token, this token will be look up in the database to get the user related to this token. How could be a token generate in order to prevent collisions in the database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ThePHPLeague OAuth2 library uses the helper class to generate random keys.

If you are using PHP look at : [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)()

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/master/src/Util/SecureKey.php

Specifically:

```
class DefaultAlgorithm implements KeyAlgorithmInterface
{

    public function generate($len = 40)
    {
        $stripped = '';
        do {
            $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len, $strong);
            // We want to stop execution if the key fails because, well, that is bad.
            if ($bytes === false || $strong === false) {

                throw new \Exception('Error Generating Key');

            }
            $stripped .= str_replace(['/', '+', '='], '', base64_encode($bytes));
        } while (strlen($stripped) < $len);
        return substr($stripped, 0, $len);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen that code before but this code doesn't check if that token exists in the DB associated to a user.

Comment: No, if you want to check for collissions just add that into a foreach to regenerate tokens... but why would you check for colissions, refresh_tokens still require client_id and client_secret. Don't worry about checking for collissions.

Comment: I am using client_credentials so client_id and client_secret are the same for all the applications involved. Which is different is the username and password but following the protocol, refreshing a token wouldn't need this data again

Comment: client_credentials specifically says that you cannot use a refresh token. I actually posted a question today on that very point...  In the spec it says you shoudl not use refresh_token

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233772/why-is-a-refresh-token-not-provided-by-oauth2-servers-responding-to-a-client-cr

Comment: Well, I think I misunderstood the protocol. My approach is to use in my app my own API letting my users log in and use my platform. Maybe do I need Resource Owner Password Credential flow?

Comment: Yep. resource owner and passwords would be the one

Comment: Ok, in that case, my question is valid again. How could be a refresh token generated in order to prevent collisions in the database?

Comment: The table should have a unique index, so just catch that failure and try again.