# Why is a refresh_token not provided by OAuth2 servers responding to a "client_credentials" grant?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I'm reading the OAuth2 spec:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2

Specially the section on `client_credentials` grant type.

> If the access token request is valid and authorized, the
> authorization server issues an access token as described in    Section
> 5.1.
> **A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.**  If the request    failed client authentication or is invalid, the authorization server
> returns an error response as described in Section 5.2.

An example successful response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

`

---

I'm somewhat confused why an authorization server can return refresh_tokens for `password` grant types but not for `client_credentials`.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the fact that the refresh_token can be exchanged for an access_token and because the client_credentials grant type does not require a username and password, in the event that your application keys and refresh_token is compromised revocation becomes much more difficult?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using the client credentials grant, the client application authenticates to the authorization server using its client id and client secret. It gets back an access token for the resource if authorized. There's no user interaction in this scenario, so there's no need to issue a refresh token.

When the access token expires, the client can use its own credentials to request a new token. Refresh tokens are used when the client want to access a resource on behalf of the user (which may not be interacting with the client at that time).

In this case, the client is acting on its own behalf.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: refresh tokens are not bound to the "accessing on behalf of" semantics, but rather to "long-lived access" semantics.A counter example to your suggestion is the JWT extension grant where a client can get an access token based on some JWT that was issued by a server, not involving a user. Now the JWT may be a one-time usage credential but the client would want long-lived access: in that case it would receive a refresh token alongside of the access token so that it can refresh the access token when it expires (and since it cannot re-use the one-time JWT grant).

Comment: i think refresh tokens are used to swap for an access token, inorder to fetch data from resource.

Answer (score 9):

The key part to understand this, is that the `refresh` concept is NOT designed for you to refresh a whatever access token you already have.

The "refresh token" is simply a way to skip end user intervention and still regain a new access token, IF your app is using end user username/password authentication, i.e. acting on behalf of a specific end user. (If I were the designer, I might name "refresh token" as "bypass-user-intervention token", so the current question wouldn't need to be asked.)

But if your app is using client credential to authenticate, it is acting on its own behalf, and you don't need user intervention at all, and the server doesn't need to (and won't) give you a refresh token either.

Comment: @HansZ. I can see both your answer and my answer are largely talking about the same thing, perhaps with slightly different emphasis. How come it is "exact opposite"?

Comment: In "the refresh concept is NOT designed for you to refresh a whatever access token" the NOT should be removed; and the refresh token is not bound to end user scenarios ie. avoiding intervention is not the root reason for its existence

Comment: May I respectfully disagree? If we remove that "NOT", the sentence would become "refresh token (RT) is designed to refresh whatever access token (AT)". Then the OP would ask "why an AT obtained by client credential grant does not come with a RT for me to refresh that AT". You see the problem here? As to your another statement "root reason for RT's existence", I just want to point out the scope for requesting a RT is named offline_access, which typically rendered as "this app would like to access your data when you are offline" in the user consent page. Isn't a RT used to skip user interaction?

Comment: I agree that the RT allows you to skip user interaction, but I'm saying that's not the reason for its existence. Following your reasoning skipping user interaction  is also what an access token allows you to do.... Would you then state that an access token is to avoid user interaction when accessing resources? Then what about the client credentials grant? What about the JWT extension grant?

Comment: Well, I can understand where you are coming from. Thanks for adding value into this conversation. I'm sure future readers would benefit from it.

Answer (score 8):

When applying the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, it makes sense to return a refresh token so that the client does not need to store or cache the Resource Owner's password - as initially provided by the Resource Owner in an interactive fashion - to get a new access token.

In the Client Credentials flow, the client's credentials are provided from storage anyway - in an off-line fashion - so the refresh token does not gain any security or usability advantage over just re-using the client credentials again (the client has access to those anyway) to get a new access token.

Comment: I would offer that there may be some advantages of using a refresh token over re-submitting credentials.

The less the credentials are communicated, the less chance that they're exposed in some way.

Also, some systems use password hashing mechanisms like bcrypt, that intentionally slow down hash computation. If you want to avoid that performance hit, verifying a refresh token is very likely much faster.

Comment: well in that case you are probably better off changing the client's method of authenticating to public/private key mechanisms or other, rather than using a password/symmetric key; that's a choice one does not have for ROPC