# oauth2-server-php not returning refresh token

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

Using [this oauth2 library for PHP](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php), I am validating a user via client_credentials like this:

server.php

```
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage, [
'access_lifetime' => 3600, // 1 hour
'refresh_token_lifetime' => 50400, // 14 days
]);

$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($server->getStorage('client_credentials'), ['always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true])));
```

Then in my endpoint (token.php):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';    
$request = OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals();
$server->handleTokenRequest($request)->send(); //returns the token object
```

Although a new access_token is returned, no refresh_token is returned:

```
{"access_token":"501a3d087db7532d4e4350402f9a5da332d71dfc","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}
```

How do you get the refresh_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour.
With the Client Credentials grant type the refresh tokens are useless because the client can get a new access token by asking a new one when he wants.

Moreover I found [a closed issue](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/issues/195) where the author of the library you use clearly explains that there is no bug here.

As mentioned in this answer, you will find in the [RFC6749 section 4.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) that the `refresh token SHOULD NOT be included`.

You can also read [this question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233772/why-is-a-refresh-token-not-provided-by-oauth2-servers-responding-to-a-client-cr).

Comment: Perfect. [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233772/why-is-a-refresh-token-not-provided-by-oauth2-servers-responding-to-a-client-cr) is also good a resource for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify `accessType: 'offline'` in the OAuth2 options to receive a refresh token. If the former does not work try `access_type: 'offline'`.

Comment: Where would that be set? I tried this but got 500 server error: `$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage, [
    'access_lifetime' => 3600, // 1 hour
    'refresh_token_lifetime' => 50400, // 14 days
    'access_type' => 'offline'
]);`