# How to get Refresh token by calling Authorization endpoint on Identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, identityserver4

I have ASP.Net MVC client application, API.Net Web API 2 Project and Identity server 4.  I want to protect my API's from unauthorized access and hence I get a JWT token from IS4 and then pass in the header as Bearer token while making a call to API. All this works fine(Login to the application, getting the JWT token and then passing to API so that it gets called after authorizing the token). I am using IdentityModel 3.9.0 version to interact with Identity server 4 endpoints.

I am trying to get Refresh Token from identity Server 4 and which is where the problem is. I am not able to get it by calling an Authorization endpoint. I am confused there. Below is my file IS4 GetClients method in config file

I was using HybridAndClientCredentials and then found out that Refresh token flow is not supported using Client Credentials.

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
   return new List<Client>
    {
    new Client
        {
        ClientId = "client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

        AccessTokenLifetime = 1800,

        AllowOfflineAccess  = true,

        // secret for authentication
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },
        // scopes that client has access to
        AllowedScopes = { "nidhiapi", "offline_access" }            
    }
};
```

I just created a Basic console application to test my auth server and below is the code in the main method

```
   var discoveryClient = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/");
        if (discoveryClient.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(discoveryClient.Error);
            return;
        }

        // request the token from the Auth server
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(discoveryClient.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");

    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("nidhiapi");
```

I am able to get AccessToken in tokenResponse variable with the defined client and HybridClientCredentials flow

As I would like to get RefreshToken from Authorize endpoint. I tried following change in my client code with same GetClients method

```
 var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("offline_access");
```

using the above code line I get an error as "Invalid_Scope". I read about it and found that we need to use offline_access to get a refresh token

Also, I have one more question. As I was trying to figure out a solution for this, I thought of creating a tokenClient using AuthorizeEndPoint but unless I validate my client credentials, the below statement is of no use.

one more thing: what should I be passing in RequestRefreshToken method as it expects a token

```
 var authTokenClient = new TokenClient(discoveryClient.AuthorizeEndpoint, "client", "secret");

 var refreshTokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync("offline_access");
```

I then tried changing my GetClients method to use Hybrid flow only and not HybridClientCredentials as I also read that RefreshToken flow is not available for ClientCredentials.

Actually, I am confused now. My requirement is to get a token from IS4 and then refresh it using refresh token so that MVC client application does not have to log in on expiration

Suggestion/Solution, please?

Comment: I don't think refresh tokens are supported (or necessary) when using client credentials for access since the client can just use their credentials to request a new access token when the current access token expires. See this SO question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233772/why-is-a-refresh-token-not-provided-by-oauth2-servers-responding-to-a-client-cr

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the authorization code flow, and you need to request the "openid offline_access" scope. As far as i'm aware, you can only use the refresh tokens when using the authorization code flow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually in IS4 hybrid flow supports refresh tokens as well

Answer (score 0):

its been a while but i am sure my answer will help someone. To get a refresh token in ID4 along with the access token, you need to specify the offiline_access in client scope and while requesting for token.
Lets take the example of username/password based token generation. The client should look like this

```
Client
            {
                ClientId = clientName,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedScopes = { apiResourceName, "offline_access" },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 63113904,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 63113904,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 63113904
            }
```

After this, when you call the identity server you have to define the scope with apiResourceName along with offline_access to generate a refresh token along with the access token.
To generate access/refresh token, using username/apssword, you can do something like this

```
var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "http://locahost/connect/token",
            ClientId = Enumerations.Client,
            Scope = Enumerations.API+" offline_access",
            UserName = "username",
            Password = "password"
        });
```

Now you will have the response.RefreshToken along with response.AccessToken populated. If you will not specify the offline_score, you will only get null in refresh token.

Now the next part is how to generate new accesstoken using the refresh token. This is the easier part, you just need to call the /connect/token again but with refresh token and that is all you need to do. This is from identityserver documentation

```
POST /connect/token

client_id=client&
client_secret=secret&
grant_type=refresh_token&
refresh_token=hdh922
```